# Want code to add integers in array if user presses certain button

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently working on a code that continuously asks the user for a gtin code for an item they want from my text file, then asks fro the quantity they need, and then places the gtin code, the item name and price of the item in a list.However, I have also made another empty list which stores all the calculations for the final price.***I want my code, when the user has finished "shopping" to press button e.g End button and my code to add all the stored numbers in the list and output the total price of all the items.***

```
file = open("read_it.txt" , "r")
for line in file:
            line = line.strip('\n')
            print(line)

total=[]
GTIN=''
while True:
    GTIN=(input("please enter GTIN for product"))
    if GTIN.isnumeric() and len(GTIN)==8 and GTIN in open('read_it.txt').read():
        total.append(GTIN)

    Quantity=""
    while True:
        Quantity=(input("Please enter the Quantity"))
        if Quantity.isdigit():
            break
        else:
            print("enter a number!")
    else:
        print("Product Not Found")
        break

    with open("read_it.txt", "r") as text_file:
        for items in text_file:
            line = items.strip('\r\n').split(",")
            if GTIN in items:
                allprice=[]
                product = line[1]
                indprice = line[2]
                finprice = float(indprice)* float(Quantity)
                print(GTIN,product,Quantity,"£",indprice,"£",finprice)
                finprice=int(finprice)
                total.append(finprice)
                allprice.append(finprice)
                break
# if user press key :
#     final = sum(allprice)
#     print(final)
```

Comment: Before I asked this questions I read 3/4 similar questions to mine, however, it was not what I wanted exactly. I am only new to python and would like to know how something like this works in python. I have never worked with something like this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this following code, Here when user Press Enter Key then Shopping will be closed and Final Total Price will be shown, 
When Press `Enter` then the input text will be blank, So Catch that property as follows,

```
if(GTN==''):
    final = sum(allprice)
    print(final)
    break
```

Use this following Code,

```
file = open("read_it.txt" , "r")
for line in file:
            line = line.strip('\n')
            print(line)

total=[]
GTIN=''
while True:
    GTIN=(input("please enter GTIN for product"))
    if(GTN==''):
       final = sum(allprice)
       print(final)
       break
    else:
        if GTIN.isnumeric() and len(GTIN)==8 and GTIN in open('read_it.txt').read():
            total.append(GTIN)

        Quantity=""
        while True:
            Quantity=(input("Please enter the Quantity"))
            if Quantity.isdigit():
                break
            else:
                print("enter a number!")
        else:
            print("Product Not Found")
            break

        with open("read_it.txt", "r") as text_file:
            for items in text_file:
                line = items.strip('\r\n').split(",")
                if GTIN in items:
                    allprice=[]
                    product = line[1]
                    indprice = line[2]
                    finprice = float(indprice)* float(Quantity)
                    print(GTIN,product,Quantity,"£",indprice,"£",finprice)
                    finprice=int(finprice)
                    total.append(finprice)
                    allprice.append(finprice)
                    break
```

Comment: If you're going to feed someone code, you should really, at the very least explain it. You just made the problem worse, since now the OP can just c&p your code.

Comment: I have edited that code and mentioned the changes clearly when you making comment!

Comment: Thanks , it makes sense , then adding it to the end.